# Are two 2D vectors linearly dependent when $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Firstly I am fairly inexperienced in linear algebra, so I apologise for the awkward title - I'm not sure how else to describe this (or Google it either).

I was working on a proof for why a set of three vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are always linearly dependant when I came along this.

It appears that given two vectors $[x_1, x_2]^T$ and $[y_1, y_2]^T$, if $x_1y_2 = x_2y_1$ then one vector is a scalar multiple of the other. This is the case in my proof where you have to divide by zero (more accurately, divide by $x_1y_2-x_2y_1$) so I feel like this can't be a coincidence.

An example is when $x_1y_2 = x_2y_1 = 12$, we could make pairs of vectors like $v_1=[12,4]^T, v_2=[3,1]^T$ and then $v_1=4v_2$.

Does this hold for all vector pairs that satisfy the restriction and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$. If there exists a zero component, then the set of that two vectors must be linearly dependent (verify!).

Assume that no components are zero. So
$$\frac{y_2}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{x_1}=k$$
for some scalar $k$.

From above equation, we get $y_2=ky_1$ and $x_2=kx_1$. Note that
$$\begin{align}
(y_1,y_2) &= (y_1,ky_1) \\
&= y_1(1,k) \\
&= \frac{y_1}{x_1} x_1(1,k) \\
&= \frac{y_1}{x_1} (x_1,kx_1) \\
&= \frac{y_1}{x_1} (x_1,x_2)
\end{align}$$

Hence, the set $\{(y_1,y_2),(x_1,x_2)\}$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just stack the vectors on a matrix $M$ and notice that $det(M) = x_1y_2 - x_2y_1$. So, if $x_1y_2 = x_2y_1$ we have $det(M) = 0$ and then the vectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Two vectors, $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)^T$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)^T$ are linearly dependent when $$\det\pmatrix{x_1 & x_2\\ y_1 & y_2}=0$$

Well, this determinant is zero when $x_1y_2-x_2y_1=0,$ so the answer is yes.

Comment: The "system" is not letting me edit this.  I want it to say "linearly dependent."